# Php $_GET value is coming from another page, but i cant put that $_GET['id'] on the same page after submitting the from

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

After submitting the form the $_GET value which is the id of post it dissappear.
How can i put this event after submitting... with all values of form too..

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: Post your form code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hidden fields` to send additional values with `form submit`. Like this:

```
<form action="myOtherFile.php" method="GET">
  <!-- put it anywhere inside the form and give it a desired name and value -->
  <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="PutValueHere" />    

  <!-- and the rest of the form -->
  <input type="text" name="address" value="" />
  <!-- and so on ... -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit me" />
</form>
```

In the receiving PHP file you would then get the variable like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['postId']))
{
    echo "ID is: ".$_GET['postId'];
}
```

Comment: @faysal No problem., glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you. Thanks